# Should I store document files on the Web Server, or the API Server?

Tags: laravel, api, ftp

I am working on a system which will have two servers, one for the web, and one for the API, which will mostly be consumed by the mobile app that I'm working on.

I have a need to store customer document files (pdf, etc..) which will be pulled from a different system via FTP which will be automated via cron job.

Is it a good idea to put the automated pulling and storing of these documents on the API server? Or should I put this in the Web Server and just reference the document via link/url since these two servers will be sharing the same database anyway?

Or are both these implementations so bad that I should actually request to have a different server/repository to store these files somewhere else, like Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend decoupling your web and API servers from your underlying storage mechanism if you foresee your project needing to scale in the near future.  Consider the requirement to add multiple web/api servers in a load-balanced environment.  Using a service like S3 makes it much easier to storage and retrieve those files from ANY server in your farm, and is unaffected by high load, full disk etc... on your application servers.  Since this question is tagged with Laravel, I would recommend you take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem to see the "out of the box" storage providers.